# C++ Error with inheritence code (no matching constructor)

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm working on an assignment for my Computer Science class based on inheritence and have been getting this one error that I can't seem to fix. If any of you could walk me through what's wrong that would be great! Thank you!

This is my Error Report

> main.cpp:199:21: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Faculty'
>     ...Faculty("Nancy","San Bernardino","555-555-5555","nancy@coolpeople.com","CSE", "5000.","September 27th","Professor","visiting"));
>
> main.cpp:169:10: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments,
>         but 9 were provided
>   Faculty::Faculty()
>            ^
>
> main.cpp:175:10: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 10 arguments,
>         but 9 were provided
>   Faculty::Faculty(string n, string a, string t, string e, string o, strin...
>            ^
>   
> main.cpp:156:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
>         viable: requires 1 argument, but 9 were provided
>   class Faculty : public Employee

And this is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
  Person();
  Person(string n, string a, string t, string e);
  string getName();
  string getAddress();
  string getTelephone();
  string getEmail();
  virtual string whatami();

private:

  string n;
  string a;
  string t;
  string e;
};

Person::Person(){}

Person::Person(string n, string a, string t, string e)
{
  this->n=n;
  this->a=a;
  this->t=t;
  this->e=e;
}

string Person::getName()
{
  return n;
}

string Person::getAddress()
{
  return a;
}

string Person::getTelephone()
{
  return t;
}

string Person::getEmail()
{
  return e;
}

string Person::whatami()
{
  return "Person";
}

class Student : virtual public Person
{
public:
  Student();
  Student(string n, string a, string t, string e, string s);
  string getStatus();
  virtual string whatami(){return "Student";};

private:
  string status;
};

Student::Student()
{
  string status = "";
}

Student::Student(string n, string a, string t, string e, string s) : Person(n,a,t,e)
{
  status = s;
}
string Student::getStatus()
{
  return status;
}

class Employee : virtual public Person
{
public:
  Employee();
  Employee(string n, string a, string t, string e, string o, string p,      string d);
  string getOffice();
  string getPayment();
  string getDatehired();
  virtual string whatami(){return "Employee";};
private:
  string office;
  string payment;
  string datehired;
};
Employee::Employee()
{
  string office = " ";
  string payment = " ";
  string datehired = " ";
}

Employee::Employee(string n, string a, string t, string e, string o, string p, string d) : Person(n,a,t,e)
{
  office = o;
  payment = p;
  datehired = d;
}

string Employee::getOffice()
{
  return office;
}
string Employee::getPayment()
{
  return payment;
}
string Employee::getDatehired()
{
  return datehired;
}

class Staff : virtual public Employee
{
public:
  Staff();
  Staff(string n,string a, string t, string e, string o, string s,      string d, string j);
  string getJobtitle();
  virtual string whatami(){return "Staff";};

private:
  string jobtitle;
};

Staff::Staff()
{
  jobtitle = "";
}

Staff::Staff(string n, string a, string t, string e, string o, string p, string d, string j) : Person(n,a,t,e),Employee(n,a,t,e,o,p,d)
{
  jobtitle = j;
}

string Staff::getJobtitle()
{
  return jobtitle;
}

class Faculty : public Employee
{
public:
  Faculty();
  Faculty(string n, string a, string t, string e, string o, string p, string d, string j, string r, string f);
  string getRank();
  string getStatus();
  virtual string whatami(){return "Faculty";};
private:
  string rank;
  string fstatus;
};

Faculty::Faculty()
{
  rank = "";
  fstatus = "";
}

Faculty::Faculty(string n, string a, string t, string e, string o, string p, string d, string j, string r, string f) : Person(n,a,t,e),Employee(n,a,t,e,o,p,d)
{
  rank = r;
  fstatus = f;
}

string Faculty::getRank()
{
  return rank;
}

string Faculty::getStatus()
{
  return fstatus;
}



int main()
{
  vector<Person*> v;
  v.push_back(new Person("John Adams","Boston","617-555-0000","john@adams.com"));
  v.push_back(new Student("John Quincy Adams","Boston","617-555-0000","johnq@adams.com","senior"));
  v.push_back(new Staff("Samuel Adams","Boston","617-555-BEER","sam@adams.com","brewhouse 1","1000","9-15-1764","Brewer"));
    v.push_back(new Faculty("Nancy","San Bernardino","555-555-5555","nancy@coolpeople.com","CSE", "5000.","September 27th","Professor","visiting"));

  for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << v[i]->getName() << " " <<v[i]->getAddress() << "  " << v[i]->getTelephone() << " " << v[i]->getEmail() << " " << classify(v[i]) <` endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful to get any help that I can!!

Comment: What exactly of the error message do you not understand ?

Comment: Please consider some sort of builder pattern if you have that many parameters. No one can be expected to remember the purpose and order of 10 strings, even with Intellisense because the names are all single letters.

Comment: if the parameter names were longer than just one character the error would be more obvious too. Modern ide's don't require you to type all that much.

Comment: Consider passing the strings to your constructor as `const std::string&` (constant reference).  This will prevent the compiler from generating copies and passing the copies to the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Faculty` constructor expects 10 strings; you provided only 9 (just as the message says).

Comment: Oh, I assumed for some reason that the 9 strings error was part of the member functions, I didn't check the int main. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Meryl, The compiler gave you the location (and the relevant code).

Comment: It did. Looking back at it now, I don't know why I was stuck at such a simple error.